# Contact query not working when filtering by Id

Tags: apex, soql

I have the following query in a remote action method being called from my visual force page:

```
List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = :nameQuery];
```

Where nameQuery is the parameter to the method and it is 0034100000wo3gcaab according to debug log...

When I put that query into the query editor in the dev console, I get one result back as expected. When I run it on my Visual Force page, I don't get anything returned, and the debug log shows that no rows came back from the query...

I don't get what is wrong with the query... How can I search contacts based on their Id if the above query doesn't work in apex?

Edit: (Adding More Code)

VisualForce page calling the remote method, and using the results to update the dataSource of a kendo Widget.

```
if (e.filter != undefined && e.filter != null) {
                        if (e.filter.value.length >= 3) {
                            console.log(e.filter.value);
                            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.MeetingRequestController.getContactsAndLeads}', e.filter.value, function(result, event) {
                                result = he.decode(result);
                                console.log(result);
                                var resultArray = JSON.parse(result);
                                //console.log(e);
                                console.log(resultArray);
                                for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
                                    var person = resultArray[i];

                                    var index = clientSearch.findIndex(function(e) {
                                        if (e.userId == person.userId) {
                                            return true;
                                        } else {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                    if (index == -1) {
                                        clientSearch.push(person);
                                    }
                                }
                                e.sender.dataSource.data(clientSearch);
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

My remote action method in my controller, getting all leads and contacts that match the search criteria, which I want to be either a name or an Id

```
@RemoteAction
global static String getContactsAndLeads(String nameQuery){

    system.debug(nameQuery);
    //nameQuery = nameQuery + '*';
    String wcNameQuery = '%'+nameQuery+'%';
    //system.debug(nameQuery);
    eventResource contactLead = new eventResource();
    List<eventResource> contactsLeadsList = new List<eventResource>();

    //Get list of all contacts

    List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE :wcNameQUery OR Id = :nameQuery];
    //Loop through each contact
    for(Integer i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++){
        //Set up contactLead, which is an eventOwner object, with data from each contact, if the contact has a name.
        if(contactList[i].Name != null){
            contactLead.name = contactList[i].Name;
            contactLead.alias = contactList[i].Name;
            contactLead.descriptor = contactList[i].Account.Name;
            contactLead.searchName = contactList[i].Name + contactList[i].Id;
            contactLead.userId = contactList[i].Id;
            contactLead.color = '#55b14e';
            contactLead.resourceType = 'Contact';
            contactLead.email = contactList[i].Email;
            //Add contactLead to our list of contacts and leads
            contactsLeadsList.add(contactLead);
        }
        //Set contactLead to a new eventOwner object
        contactLead = new eventResource();
    }

    //Get list of all Leads

    List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Company FROM Lead WHERE Name LIKE :wcNameQuery OR Id = :nameQuery];
    //Loop through each Lead
    for(Integer i = 0; i < leadList.size(); i++){
        //Set up contactLead, which is an eventOwner object, with data from each lead, if lead has a name
        if(leadList[i].Name != null){
            contactLead.name = leadList[i].Name;
            contactLead.alias = leadList[i].Name;
            contactLead.descriptor = leadList[i].Company;
            contactLead.searchName = leadList[i].Name + leadList[i].Id;
            contactLead.userId = leadList[i].Id;
            contactLead.color = '#c13e3e';
            contactLead.resourceType = 'Lead';
            contactLead.email = leadList[i].Email;
            //Add contactLead to our list of contacts and leads
            contactsLeadsList.add(contactLead);
        }
        //Set contactLead to a new eventOwner object
        contactLead = new eventResource();
    }

    return JSON.serialize(contactsLeadsList);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more code so that I can see what your visualforce page is doing and what the rest of your code is doing.

Comment: Edited to show relevant code

Comment: Are you logged in as the same user during all the testing?

Comment: Yes I am, with admin privileges.

Comment: Doing a Name LIKE :wcNameQuery where clause works fine, I can type in the name and get results. But Id = :nameQuery where nameQuery is an Id returns nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your variable "nameQuery" as an Id before using it in your query:

```
Id nameQueryId = ( Id )nameQuery;
```

Then your query might work better. Also consider sharing for Contacts. does your controller run "with sharing"? possibly if you are not the owner it will not show - even with your admin privileges. try also modifying the class to be "without sharing" to test your output and see if you get any results.